# Where to find X-ray videos of the vocal track for all the English vowels?

Tags: pronunciation, vowels, consonants, ipa

I've found [this web page](https://improveyouraccent.co.uk/teaching-vowels-physically/#9b5bb9b2c80cd801c) that makes a convincing case for teaching/studying the [cardinal vowel quadrilateral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_vowels#Table_of_cardinal_vowels) in language learning. Apparently it is taught to improve the accent to actors, and in some advanced language courses.

So, I was wondering where to find videos with the English vowels (and maybe some difficult consonants), showing the vocal track in X-ray, so I can have a better idea where the "real" position of the tongue is when visualizing the quadrilateral.

What I've found so far is [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qtGHv1a4b48) showing only the vowels used in Spanish. And [these other videos](https://www.youtube.com/user/ArticulatoryIPA/videos) that I guess are mostly oriented to phoneticians.

Comment: Have you looked at [Sounds of Speech](http://soundsofspeech.uiowa.edu/)? Not X-ray but far better to my mind.

Comment: @Laure The images are simplified, but I don't know if that's a good think. I generally learn physical activities by seeing the real thing, then the kinesthetic part of the brain kicks in and reproduce those movements physically. Although there is definitely something odd I can't put my finger on with the X-rays, maybe I am getting distracted by all the intricacies in the organic nature of the images. Or I still don't have a mental map of how those translate to my own tongue.